# ParseFloat return string instead of number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

i have a array coming from api like this

```
x = [0, 12.1, 23.45, 100.23, 13.99, 90, 0, 16.1]
```

i want each number with decimal point upto 2, like 0.00 or 12.10

what i did is

```
x = x.toFixed(x);
```

but this return string values not number, i need all values as numbers.
i am not sure how i can get numbers after converting them to decimals.

someone suggest this code i tried but no success

```
x = +x.toFixed(2);
```

i tried parseFloat as well after toFixed but it shows in console its a number but its not, its actually a string.

i am trying this in angular2+ application in primeng table

Comment: It is not possible. Numbers do not have trailing zeros. That is why it is converted to a string.

Comment: mean we are at dead end ?

Comment: Use the numbers as they are, convert them to strings (via `toFixed`) only when you need to display them.

Comment: what are you trying to achive? I believe that you are in wrong direction

Comment: Why do you need the 0's if you're doing math on them? Mathematically, `1.0000000000 == 1`. The only time you should need leading 0s or trailing decimal 0s is when you're displaying them, not operating on them; in which case, as @ibrahimmahrir said, make a string copy for display but operate on the original numbers.

Comment: @Simonare i want to display each number with 2 values after dot if its 0 it will display like 0.00 if its 1.1 it will display like 1.10

Comment: Where are you displaying them? You should use `toFixed` there.

Comment: in primeng table in angular app

Comment: check my answer please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use pipe on the html side

{{x | number:'1.1-3'}}

Reference: https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#example

PS: dont forget to add DecimalPipe inside your declarations

If your need is to use this on ts side then your solution would work

```
(15).toFixed(2) //15.00
```

Comment: i think it should be `{{x | number:'1.2-2'}}`. the number of digits to the right of the decimal should always be 2.

Comment: i did tofixed but it return it as a string not number

Comment: anyway thanks, display with number is a good idea and it works :)